# How can a reference require no storage?

Tags: c++, variables, compiler-construction, reference

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744675/size-of-references-in-64bit-environments), and consequently, from the Standard (ISO C++-03):

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

In some answers in that thread, it's said that references have, internally, the same structure of a pointer, thus, having the same size of it (32/64 bits).

What I'm struggling to grasp is: how would a reference come **not** to require storage?

Any sample code exemplifying this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:
From @JohannesSchaub-litb comment, is there anything like, if I'm not using a `const &`, or if I'm using a `const &` with default value, it requires allocation? It seems to me, somehow, that there should be no allocations for references at all -- except, of course, when there are explicit allocations involved, like:

```
A& new_reference(*(new A())); // Only A() instance would be allocated,
                              // not the new_reference itself
```

Is there any case like this?

Comment: They can be optimized out by the compiler, for example. Or a weird architecture may use a different way of storing them. In some cases they don't have to be stored at all; `int a = 0; int& b = a;` even storing `b` here is a waste of memory. Note that references are not objects and shouldn't be thought of as such.

Comment: A reference is just an alias. I believe for the compiler it is just a matter of allowing different names for the same variable.

Comment: You know that `*(new A())` kills a kitten, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take something simple:

```
int foo() {
  int  x = 5;
  int& r = x;
  r = 10;
  return x;
}
```

The implementation *may* use a pointer to `x` behind the scenes to implement that reference, but there's no reason it has to. It could just as well translate the code to the equivalent form of:

```
int foo() {
  int x = 10
  return x;
}
```

Then no pointers are needed whatsoever. The compiler can just bake it right into the executable that `r` is the same as `x`, without storing and dereferencing a pointer that points at `x`.

The point is, whether the reference requires any storage is an implementation detail that you shouldn't need to care about.

Comment: what's the normative use of the rule he quoted? Can you show an example that would break if references required storage?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Why does there have to be such an example? It says it is unspecified whether they require storage, not that they must not require storage.

Comment: using storage is not part of the observable behavior of an implementation, so there doesn't need to be a rule granting the non-usage. There is no normative rule that says "Whether or not functions require storage is unspecified.", even though C++ says in a note that functions may use storage in the way objects do.

Comment: In your example, an implementation may use no storage for `x` either. It can just erase the whole body of `foo`.

Comment: From @JohannesSchaub-litb comment, is there anything like, if I'm not using a `const &`, or if I'm using a `const &` with default value, it requires allocation? From your example it seems somehow that there should be no allocations at all -- except, of course, when you're explicitly allocating something. Is there any case like this? I'll add this to the question.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think it's just a fairly pointless rule that is only there to stop people asking "How can I get a pointer to a reference?" or "What is the size of a reference?". Maybe it has some obscure effect on something else in the standard but I don't know what that is.

Comment: @JosephMansfield using storage is part of the observable behaviour if the reference is contained within a `struct` and the program checks `sizeof` that struct

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key point to understanding is that reference types are *not* object types.

> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a
>   void type `(§3.9[basic.types]/8)`

Objects require storage ("An object is a region of storage." -- §1.8[intro.object]/1)

Moreover, C++ programs operate on objects: "The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects." -- same paragraph

So, when the compiler encounters a reference in the program, it is up to the compiler whether it has to synthesize an *object* (typically of a pointer type), and, therefore, use some storage, or find some other way to implement the desired semantics in terms of object model (which may involve no storage).